# regarding the meaning of "put" in SAS

Tags: sas

what does the following SAS statement mean?

```
select(substr(put(customerID, 4.),3,2));
```

Especially, what do the three parameters 4., 3, and 2 stand for? Thanks

Comment: As Banjer says, put converts your numeric value to character.  [This PDF from SAS](http://support.sas.com/publishing/pubcat/chaps/59498.pdf) is my favorite reference for the puts, inputs, and so on that are used in SAS programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are first converting customerID to a character format so that you can extract a string from it using the substr function.

`put(customerID, 4.)`

Converts a numeric value to a character value of length 4.

`substr(myvar,3,2)`

Returns the substring of length 2, starting from position 3 (from the left) of string myvar.  In SAS, the very first character on the left is position 1, compared to most other programming languages and the world of computer science where you start with 0.  myvar MUST be a character (string) variable.

I'm not familiar with the select() function, but your question seemed geared towards the substr and put functions.

Answer (score 1):

The SELECT looks like it is part of a case statement where your logic will branch depending upon what is contained in the select function:

Example:

```
select (a);
   when (1) x=x*10;
   when (2);
   when (3,4,5) x=x*100;
   otherwise;
end;
```